# Azure Mobile App CORS settings

Tags: azure-mobile-services

I am trying to migrate a Mobile Service .NET backend to a Mobile App .NET backend.

For the Mobile Service, I am able to configure CORS settings on the management portal and in web.config for local development settings, e.g.

```
<add key="MS_CrossDomainOrigins" value="http://localhost:8100"/>
```

How do I configure the CORS settings for a Mobile App  ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

CORS is the Apps world is now configured via the standard Web API models.

Something like so:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("www.mysite.com", "*", "*");
        config.EnableCors(cors);
    }
}
```

See: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api

Answer (score 0):

You can also configure allowed CORS domains through the Azure Portal under Settings -> CORS